# Larave 8 Cronjob not working with Hostinger shared service

Tags: bash, cron, laravel-8

I have created a schedule to send emails after a given time and this works perfectly locally.
My code is very standard and I don't think there's anything wrong with that.

This is because locally it works perfectly with the `php artisan schedule:run` command.

Since the cronjob input field in the Hosginger service **does not allow special characters**, I had to create a bash file.

This is my bash file(path: app/Console/cron.sh).

```
#!/bin/sh
php /home/uidnumber/domains/domain_name/public_html/laraveldirectory/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

And this sh file was registered in cronjob.

However, the expected behavior does not proceed.

To make sure the bash file is working, I tried the following to confirm the bash file is called correctly.

I created a `script.php` file in the root directory and changed `cron.sh` file like following.

```
#!/bin/sh
php /home/uidnumber/domains/domain_name/public_html/laraveldirectory/script.php cron:run > /dev/null 2>&1
```

For reference, in `script.php`, I wrote a script that puts dummy data in a specific table in the DB for testing.
This worked perfectly.

In summary, my thoughts are:

1. I think there is no problem with the schedule code because it works perfectly on local with the command `php artisan schedule:run`.
2. The bash file call was also confirmed through the execution of the `script.php` file.

So.. I can guess that something is wrong with the following command in the bash file, but I couldn't succeed despite trying various ways.

```
#!/bin/sh
php /home/uidnumber/domains/domain_name/public_html/laraveldirectory/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Can anyone help me what I have to fix?

Comment: It's kind of crazy to me that you'd ask a question with tags bash, cron and php. At least narrow your issue down to one of these three before asking.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure what the problem is with this.
Of course, I deleted the php tag because I think this is not a php problem.

Comment: and yet the question is full of php

Comment: Often cron issues are because something about the cron environment is not the same as your home environment. Either the cron user has different permissions, or the cron run directory is different to how you tested it, or something like that. You are directing output to /dev/null so you'll lose any output from the command.  Make sure you've tried running it AS the cron user IN the cron directory, and redirect output to a file so you can examine it for clues.

Comment: If I puth `php /home/uidnumber/domains/domain_name/public_html/laraveldirectory/script.php cron:run > /dev/null 2>&1` in to bash file then this is working well.
So I can see that the bash file is actually executed.

Comment: When you say it worked perfectly locally, how did you run it?

Comment: Executed with this command `php artisan schedule:run` on my console.

Comment: Step 1 when having trouble is to try to see what is happening.  You are `/dev/null`ing both output and errors, so you are hiding any clues about the problem from yourself - get rid of that.  I doubt it is the problem but `1>> /dev/null 2>&1` is also odd, what is the purpose of the initial `1`?  "*this sh file was registered in cronjob*" - what does this mean, *exactly*?  Have you tried fully-qualifying the path to `php`, eg like `/usr/local/bin/php` or wherever it is?

Comment: Yes. I agree with your opinion. I need to trace the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cron jobs do not generally have the same environment, so you have to specify the full path to `php` (e.g. `/bin/php`). A lot of times these services have multiple `php` versions, so the correct one might be under a different `PATH`.

What I would do is create a script that outputs all the relevant information and then take a look at what's different from an environment that works:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
env >> /tmp/env.txt
command -v php >> /tmp/php.txt
```

Generally when debugging these kinds of problems you have get rid of all the assumptions, including that `php` is available.

Comment: Yes, of course, your opinion makes sense.
However, as I mentioned, the cronjob is executed even if do not specify the PHP full path for script.php.
Also when I put full path I get same result.

Comment: @Silverstar But you never specified what is the result that you are getting, only that is "not expected". Before sending the output of the command to `/dev/null` it would be better to see what the php command throws, a lot times cron is configured to send mails to the root account with the output, that might give you some hint. But if php is being called correctly, then this question has nothing to do with bash, and you should check your server's mail configuration.

Comment: @Silverstar You should try to send mail with the linux `mail` command from the shell script, and if that works send a mail using php's `mail` function.

Comment: I traced the log and there I got the following message:
"Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.0.2". You are running 7.4.30."
However, the version of PHP running on the server is definitely v8.0.2.
To fix this I ran  `composer install --ignore-platform-reqs` and it solved my problem, but I don't understand why I got the above Exception. Any idea?

Comment: Your server possibly has multiple versions of PHP installed.  One of them is in the `PATH`, and that's the one you get if you use `php` without qualifying it. If you need a different version, you should fully qualify it, like `/usr/local/bin/php8` or whatever - you'll need to find out where it is.  Or maybe you simply need to [change the "global" version of PHP your server uses](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-change-your-php-version)? I'm not familiar with Hostinger, I just found that when looking for info about different CLI versions.

Comment: These types of services usually have multiple users per machine, so you can't change the php version of the machine, when you select a php version in the cPanel what it's doing is changing the `$PATH` variable to something like `/usr/lib/php8/bin` where there's a php binary.

Comment: Yes, the Hostinger service allows to select the php version in cPanel.
Anyway, the PHP script runs fine. It has definitely been confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess your testing user has important variables set in `.profile`, `.bashrc`, or something like that which allows the `php artisan schedule:run` command to run, in or out of a script.  I've encountered similar problems in the past with Java programs.

Cron does not launch a shell, and thus will not obtain any variables set outside of the script.  Make sure any environment variables you need to run the script are present within the script.

This includes information about where the script is located.  If running a command relies on an environment file in the current working directory, it will not work in a cronjob unless that directory is changed into during the execution of the script.

Comment: Turn your attention to that this worked fine for the command in `php artisan schedule:run` locally. This means that the necessary environment variables have been successfully loaded in the script. Also, since this command executes the `artisan` command, there should be no problem in actually executing the structure of the Laravel project if working well artisan command.

Comment: @Silverstar you misunderstand.  The environment on your local machine is likely very different from the server.  Variables like `$PATH` for eg will not be the same, and are how the shell will find things like `php`, which you have not qualified.

Comment: Additionally, it's possible the php command will not work as expected with fully qualified paths, but I'm not familiar enough to say with certainty.  Modifying the shell script to `cd <app directory>` first might help too.

Comment: I see you mentioned it in comments on your OP.  That's a good thing.  Type `env` and put the output in your OP, this could help identify the problem.